# MongoDB CRUD operations with Drupal

Tags: mongodb, drupal

I am new to Drupal.  How to perform CRUD operations in MongoDB?

I have enabled the `mongodb` module and followed [related instructions](http://spf13.com/post/getting-started-with-drupal-and-mongodb), but it still does not work.